# How to match $_SESSION with if..else?

Tags: php

Here i have an `if else` that create cookie with name `check_CookiesRW` and with content randomly generated by `rand(1000,999999);`. I would love to check if the cookie content randomly generated and stored on `$_SESSION` would match and `echo` out **Cookie is SET** something like  this

`if(isset($_COOKIE['check_CookiesRW']) && $_COOKIE['check_CookiesRW'] === $_SESSION['cookie_content'])`

how can i achieve this without it throwing out error **Warning: Undefined variable $_SESSION** ??

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE['check_CookiesRW'])) {
print "<h1>Cookie is SET</h1>";

} else {
    
$cookie_name = "check_CookiesRW";
$cookie_content = rand(1000,999999);
$_SESSION['cookie_content'] = $cookie_content;

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_content, time()+30, "/");
print "<h1>Created Cookie</h1>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Do you start the session?

Comment: @user3783243 i'm mad i've been traying to troubleshoot this in the last 3 hours and i didn't know you need `session_start();` to be avail to use `$_SESSION` ... i must search the function i'm using first before asking question since `session_start();` was indicated a must for  `$_SESSION`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php